# Fatal error: Call to a member function connection() on null

Tags: connection, fatal-error, laravel-5.3, directadmin

I am using Laravel 5.3.26.
Whene I upload your project in DirectAdmin Host, happening this error?

> Fatal error: Call to a member function connection() on null in /home/kwni/domains/kwni.ir/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 3348.

And my composer.json file :
[image]

What can be the cause of this error?

Comment: Are you sure you've setup the database connection correctly? Is the mysql running?

Comment: yes, are sure. it is run.